# Spark iterate HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

I have a directory of directories on HDFS, and I want to iterate over the directories.  Is there any easy way to do this with Spark using the SparkContext object?

Comment: you mean 'iterate' like get the list of sub-directories and files within? or getting all files across all subdirectories?

Comment: Iterate as in list all the sub-directories.  Each subdirectory contains a bunch of text files that I want to process in different ways.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html).  Specifically, `FileSystem.listFiles([path], true)`

And with Spark...

```
FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration).listFiles(..., true)
```

**Edit**

It's worth noting that good practice is to get the `FileSystem` that is associated with the `Path`'s scheme.

```
path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration).listFiles(path, true)
```

Comment: really nice! [I had this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738296/spark-spark-submit-jars-arguments-wants-comma-list-how-to-declare-a-directory/35550151#35550151), granted, I guess this wouldn't work in the original spark-submit call

Comment: How can I create a list of the files using the RemoteIterator this creates?

Answer (score 45):

Here's PySpark version if someone is interested:

```py
    hadoop = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop

    fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
    conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration() 
    path = hadoop.fs.Path('/hivewarehouse/disc_mrt.db/unified_fact/')

    for f in fs.get(conf).listStatus(path):
        print(f.getPath(), f.getLen())
```

In this particular case I get list of all files that make up disc_mrt.unified_fact Hive table.

Other methods of FileStatus object, like getLen() to get file size are described here:

[Class FileStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#FileStatus--)

Comment: an upvote for pyspark version! worked perfectly! thanks!

Comment: thank U! was wondering how to make it in python

Comment: how to recursively do this ? it doesn't list the files under the directory.

Comment: @GaurangShah create a function, and recursively call it if `f` object is a directory

Answer (score 21):

```
import  org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem,Path}

FileSystem.get( sc.hadoopConfiguration ).listStatus( new Path("hdfs:///tmp")).foreach( x => println(x.getPath ))
```

This worked for me.

Spark version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.2

Comment: This worked fine for me, for a single folder.  Is there some way to get this to run at the level of the parent folder, and get all files in all subfolders?  That would be VERY helpful/useful for me.

Comment: have you got any solution to recursively  look for directories and then finally extrct files?

Answer (score 2):

this did the job for me

```
FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://HAservice:9000"), sc.hadoopConfiguration).listStatus( new Path("/tmp/")).foreach( x => println(x.getPath ))
```

Answer (score 2):

@Tagar didn't say how to connect remote hdfs, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258750/1637673) did:

```
URI           = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration


fs = FileSystem.get(URI("hdfs://somehost:8020"), Configuration())

status = fs.listStatus(Path('/some_dir/yet_another_one_dir/'))

for fileStatus in status:
    print(fileStatus.getPath())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scala**
[FileSystem (Apache Hadoop Main 3.2.1 API)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html)

```scala
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    
    val fileSystem : FileSystem = {
        val conf = new Configuration()
        conf.set( "fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://to_file_path" )
        FileSystem.get( conf )
    }
      
    val files = fileSystem.listFiles( new Path( path ), false )
    val filenames = ListBuffer[ String ]( )
    while ( files.hasNext ) filenames += files.next().getPath().toString()
    filenames.foreach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with other answers(like 'JavaObject' object is not iterable), but this code works for me

```
fs = self.spark_contex._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark_contex._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
i = fs.listFiles(spark_contex._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path), False)
while i.hasNext():
  f = i.next()
  print(f.getPath())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with globStatus status as well

```
val listStatus = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new URI(url), sc.hadoopConfiguration).globStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(url))

      for (urlStatus <- listStatus) {
        println("urlStatus get Path:"+urlStatus.getPath())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to iterate **recursivly** through a parent HDFS directory, storing only sub-**directories** up to a third level. This is useful, if you need to list all directories that are created due to the partitioning of the data (in below code three columns were used for partitioning):

```scala
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

def rememberDirectories(fs: FileSystem, path: List[Path]): List[Path] = {
  val buff = new ListBuffer[LocatedFileStatus]()

  path.foreach(p => {
    val iter = fs.listLocatedStatus(p)
    while (iter.hasNext()) buff += iter.next()
  })

  buff.toList.filter(p => p.isDirectory).map(_.getPath)
}

@tailrec
def getRelevantDirs(fs: FileSystem, p: List[Path], counter: Int = 1): List[Path] = {
  val levelList = rememberDirectories(fs, p)
  if(counter == 3) levelList
  else getRelevantDirs(fs, levelList, counter + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good.
Here is bonus including their sizes and file counts
FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize will display their sizes in MB or KB i.e. human readable form

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object ListFilesRecursive {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("ListFilesRecursive")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
  def listFilesRecursive(path: Path): (Seq[Path], Long, Int) = {
    val fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri, spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val statuses = fs.listStatus(path)
    var subDirCount = 0
    var size = 0L
    var numFiles = 0
    for (status <- statuses) {
      if (status.isDirectory) {
        val (subFiles, subSize, subCount) = listFilesRecursive(status.getPath)
        numFiles += subCount
        size += subSize
        subDirCount += 1
        println(s"status.getPath ${status.getPath}\t subSize ${FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(subSize)}\tsubCount $subCount")
      } else {
        val fileSize = status.getLen
        numFiles += 1
        size += fileSize
        println(s"${status.getPath}\t${FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(fileSize)}\t1")
      }
    }
    (statuses.map(_.getPath).toSeq, size, numFiles + subDirCount)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val rootPath = new Path(args(0))
    val (allFiles, totalSize, totalNumFiles) = listFilesRecursive(rootPath)
    println(s"\nTotal size: ${FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(totalSize)}")
    println(s"Total number of files: $totalNumFiles")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

---

##### Result:  (argument I passed C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\scala-hive-project\user)

```
file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_partitioned_table/age=30/part-00000-0d9bd9c2-4dc4-4638-90ec-80fefd621dc7-c000   17 bytes    1
file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_partitioned_table/age=30/part-00001-0d9bd9c2-4dc4-4638-90ec-80fefd621dc7-c000   14 bytes    1
status.getPath file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_partitioned_table/age=30  subSize 31 bytes   subCount 2
status.getPath file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_partitioned_table     subSize 31 bytes   subCount 3
file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_table/part-00000-ea67892e-f8ea-4b32-bf10-592652f12735-c000  16 bytes    1
file:/C:/Users/ramgh/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_table/part-00001-ea67892e-f8ea-4b32-bf10-592652f12735-c000    13 bytes    1
status.getPath file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/sample_table     subSize 29 bytes   subCount 2
status.getPath file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db  subSize 60 bytes   subCount 7
status.getPath file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive/warehouse   subSize 60 bytes   subCount 8
status.getPath file:/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/scala-hive-project/user/hive     subSize 60 bytes   subCount 9

Total size: 60 bytes
Total number of files: 10
```

Note : I used windows with hadoop api thats the reason printing window directories in the result.
Sameway with out changing api it will work for hadoop since I used hadoop api for recursively printing