# Spark Scala list folders in directory

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I want to list all folders within a hdfs directory using Scala/Spark.
In Hadoop I can do this by using the command: `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/demo/`

I tried it with:

```
val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/"), conf)

val path = new Path("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/demo/")

val files = fs.listFiles(path, false)
```

But it does not seem that he looks in the Hadoop directory as i cannot find my folders/files.

I also tried with:

```
FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration).listFiles(new Path("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/demo/"), true)
```

But this also does not help.

Do you have any other idea?

PS: I also checked this thread: [Spark iterate HDFS directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023766/spark-iterate-hdfs-directory) but it does not work for me as it does not seem to search on hdfs directory, instead only on the local file system with schema file//.

Comment: This solution helped me with a bug. I needed to do code like
`val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("s3://mybucket/mykey"), conf)`
to get the correct FileSystem for spark to use. The default FileSystem was for hdfs.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We are using hadoop 1.4 and it doesn't have listFiles method so we use listStatus to get directories. It doesn't have recursive option but it is easy to manage recursive lookup.

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path(YOUR_HDFS_PATH))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, listStatus is much better for getting the folders and works nicely! In my case i dont need a recursive lookup, so thats perfectly fine. **One addition**: When I am using your coding, the filesystem schema is file:// and i cannot use hdfs:// as schema. So I created the Filesystem this way: `val conf = new Configuration()
     val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/"), conf)`. Then the Filesystem accepts hdfs:// paths.

Comment: "error: not found: type Configuration", how to import or prepare it? Using `import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`

Answer (score 22):

In Spark 2.0+,

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.listStatus(new Path(s"${hdfs-path}")).filter(_.isDir).map(_.getPath).foreach(println)
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

in Ajay Ahujas answer `isDir` is deprecated..

use `isDirectory`... pls see complete example and output below.

```
package examples

    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    object ListHDFSDirectories  extends  App{
      val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
      logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName(this.getClass.getName)
        .config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()

      val hdfspath = "." // your path here
      import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
      val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
      fs.listStatus(new Path(s"${hdfspath}")).filter(_.isDirectory).map(_.getPath).foreach(println)
    }
```

Result :

```
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/target
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/Rel
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/spark-warehouse
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/metastore_db
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/.idea
file:/Users/user/codebase/myproject/src
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 val listStatus = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new URI(url), sc.hadoopConfiguration)
.globStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(url))

  for (urlStatus <- listStatus) {
    println("urlStatus get Path:" + urlStatus.getPath())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same, however instead of **HDFS**, for **S3**.

I solved creating the FileSystem with my S3 path as below:

```
  def getSubFolders(path: String)(implicit sparkContext: SparkContext): Seq[String] = {
    val hadoopConf = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    val uri = new URI(path)

    FileSystem.get(uri, hadoopConf).listStatus(new Path(path)).map {
      _.getPath.toString
    }
  }
```

I know this question was related for HDFS, but maybe others like me will come here looking for S3 solution. Since without specifying the URI in FileSystem, it will look for HDFS ones.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3://<bucket>/dummy_path
expected: hdfs://<ip-machine>.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8020
```

Comment: can you put an example use of this please?

Answer (score 3):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Demo").getOrCreate()
val path = new Path("enter your directory path")
val fs:FileSystem = projects.getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val it = fs.listLocatedStatus(path)
```

This will create an iterator `it` over `org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus` that is your subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Azure Blog Storage is mapped to a HDFS location, so all the Hadoop Operations

On [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), go to Storage Account, you will find following details:

- Storage account
- Key -
- Container -
- Path pattern – /users/accountsdata/
- Date format – yyyy-mm-dd
- Event serialization format – json
- Format – line separated

Path Pattern here is the HDFS path, you can login/putty to the Hadoop Edge Node and do:

```
hadoop fs -ls /users/accountsdata
```

Above command will list all the files. In Scala you can use

```
import scala.sys.process._ 

val lsResult = Seq("hadoop","fs","-ls","/users/accountsdata/").!!
```

Comment: It helped me to get the log size in Jupyter notebook when Spark History Server has memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
object HDFSProgram extends App {    
  val uri = new URI("hdfs://HOSTNAME:PORT")    
  val fs = FileSystem.get(uri,new Configuration())    
  val filePath = new Path("/user/hive/")    
  val status = fs.listStatus(filePath)    
  status.map(sts => sts.getPath).foreach(println)    
}
```

This is sample code to get list of hdfs files or folder present under /user/hive/

Answer (score -2):

Because you're using Scala, you may also be interested in the following:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val lsResult = Seq("hadoop","fs","-ls","hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/demo/").!!
```

This will, unfortunately, return the entire output of the command as a string, and so parsing down to just the filenames requires some effort. (Use `fs.listStatus` instead.) But if you find yourself needing to run other commands where you could do it in the command line easily and are unsure how to do it in Scala, just use the command line through `scala.sys.process._`. (Use a single `!` if you want to just get the return code.)