# Get list of user who have access to a hdfs file using Spark - Java

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

From a Spark job which is written in Java,  I am trying to get the list of all the linux/centos users who have access to a particular hdfs file.

Currently tring out below Java code to get the info:

```
result = Shell.execCommand("sudo","bash","-c","lid","-g","-n", fileOwnersGroup);
```

but it is not working out. It is throwing:

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tried various option including updating /etc/sudoer but no luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Adding "in a shell script" or "in my program" is usually not enough to make the question a programming and development question. Please show your Java code and explain where the problem lies.

Comment: HDFS is not a POSIX filesystem. Your HDFS "user accounts" aren't (typically) mapped to Linux users. **Especially** if you aren't using Kerberos

Comment: Yeah, but if i have them mapped, how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

A [`FileStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) object has `getOwner()` and `getGroup()` methods.

You can get a status with a `FileSystem` object and a `Path` to a file.

For example, [Spark Scala list folders in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394884/spark-scala-list-folders-in-directory)

However, you will need some external query to find what Unix accounts map into a group. For example, such an operation would typically be controlled by an LDAP search.

> it is throwing sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Clearly the problem is that sudo is prompting  for a password and Spark processes shouldn't be able to execute elevated commands on the local filesystem

Comment: Using the same to get the owner and group, but once I have the group, I wanted to get the list of all the user belongs to that group.
from java i am using below command 
result = Shell.execCommand("sudo","bash","-c","lid","-g","-n", fileOwnersGroup);
But it is not working out.

Comment: You don't need `sudo bash -c` to read account information. Plus, you're spark applications should really not be able to run with elevated privileges anyway. Spark is a distributed execution framework, and you cannot control what server an executor runs on. User/group mapping is out of scope of the Hadoop project. As mentioned, group management is commonly controlled by LDAP. And to sync LDAP to unix accounts, one uses sssd

Comment: In any case `getent group ${group}` is the command you'd want, I believe