# cannot list files in a hdfs dir using new File.listFiles

Tags: scala

There is full permission to the folder I am trying to list but still, couldn't.

```
scala> new File("hdfs://mapdigidev/apps/hive/warehouse/da_ai.db/t_fact_ai_pi_ww").listFiles
res0: Array[java.io.File] = null
```

Comment: What tools allow you to list files and see there's something actually there?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023766/spark-iterate-hdfs-directory. You need to use the libraries that know how to handle HDFS, and java.io does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hadoop libraries to list files in hadoop:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://mapdigidev"), new Configuration())
val files = fs.listFiles(new Path("/apps/hive/warehouse/da_ai.db/t_fact_ai_pi_ww"), false)
```

But java.io doesn't know about hadoop/hdfs.