# How to get or create a Hadoop client from a Spark Executor

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

Is there any way to get the Hadoop FileSystem from a Spark Executor when performing a mapPartitions operation over a Spark Dataframe?
If not, at least is there any way to get the Hadoop configuration in order to generate a new Hadoop FileSystem?

Take into account that the HDFS is kerberized.

The use-case would be something like (pseudo-code):

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM cities").mapPartitions{ iter =>
    iter.groupedBy(some-variable).foreach{ rows =>
        hadoopFS.write(rows)
    }
    TaskContext.getPartitionId
}
```

Comment: There is a way... But why don't you just call write method on the dataframe object?

Comment: Because I want to create a kind of dynamic partitioning from the executors based on some variables. So... could you tell me that way, please?

Comment: I've modified a little bit the pseudo-code to note that calling write method is not suitable here

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027071/2308683

Comment: Given that SparkContext is not available in the executors... I don't think that the solution proposed by @cricket_007 is valid

Comment: I tried to follow the example of the suggested link but I get the next exception:


  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: 
  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
  Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, value: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml)
`

Comment: I tried to serialize the Hadoop Configuration as a json string and use it inside the mapPartitions but, even so, Hadoop Configuration couldn't be deserialized. Any idea?

Comment: You should be able to get a configuration object within each partition action using the standard `new Configuration()` constructor. Thatll pull the configuration from the classpath on its own. That way, you're not deserializing around the closure

Comment: @cricket_007 Your suggestion didn't work... It takes the default parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. Spark utils contains a very simple way of serializing the hadoop configuration: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/SerializableConfiguration.scala