# How to run HDFS file system command via Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I can run this command for HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/tablename
```

How to write command in Spark to show all files under specific folder in HDFS?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a possible copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023766/spark-iterate-hdfs-directory **FileSystem** has the majority of HDFS commands available so it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the below `scala` code just give you a function to print all the hdfs files under a parent path.You can improve it according to your needs.

```
  def getAllPaths(parentPath:String, fs: FileSystem) = {
    val fileStatus = fs.listStatus(new Path(parentPath))
    for( file<- fileStatus) {
      println(file.getPath.toString)
    }
  }
```