# Pyspark FileSystem fs.listStatus(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path)) only returns the first sub-directory

Tags: pyspark, hdfs

I want to walk through a given hdfs path recursively in Pyspark without using `hadoop fs -ls [path]`. I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023766/spark-iterate-hdfs-directory), but found that `listStatus()` only returns me the status of the first sub-directory in the given path. According to [this documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html), `listStatus` should return "the statuses of the files/directories in the given path if the path is a directory." What am I missing?

I'm using Hadoop 2.9.2, Spark 2.3.2 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Could you post your code - how exactly you are using this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't exactly recreate the scenario, but I think it has something to do with the fact that if a path is not a directory, `listStatus()` on that path will return a list of length 1 containing only the path itself.