# how to recursively traverse through given HDFS directory and fetch the filename with path in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs, cluster-computing, directory-traversal

Structure of my directory in hdfs looks like below:

----Directory

```
 |----sub folder 1
          |--------file 1
          |---------file 2
 |                          
 |----sub folder 2
            |--------file 1
            |---------file 2
 |----sub folder 3
            |--------file 1
            |---------file 2
 |----file 1
```

i want to traverse recursively through the HDFS directory to retrieve all filename and its path.

Comment: `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem#listFiles(<path>, recursive=True)`?

Comment: can you help with pyspark code to implement the above

Comment: Please refer this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178292/4758823